# styling commands over the <ol> list items

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm a late comer on working with CSS lists.  I have used this code to create lists where the first indent is a-z and the 2nd indent is roman, i, ii, iii, iv etc.:

```
/* SF/2013-10-16; this code will create 1.a.i structure similar perh. to a legal document.. */
ol > li > ol {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

ol > li > ol > li > ol {
    list-style-type: lower-roman;
}
```

BUT I wonder if there is any way to make the font of the list indexes (1,2,3, a,b,c, i,ii,iii) a different font than the actual list text itself - elegantly - and also to change the size or color of the list index.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `:before` pseudo selector to insert the roman numerals, you have full control over the styling. I used the `counter-increment` function as the content of the selector - it works pretty well!

[**Basic jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/WtSp6/)

[image]

**CSS**

```
li {
    list-style:none;
    counter-increment: name;
}
li:before {
    content: counter(name, lower-roman);
    font-size:26px;
    color:red;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

You can even play around with `nth-child`, and [**do stuff like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/e4cwK/).

```
li:first-child:before {
    content: counter(name, lower-alpha);
    font-size:40px;
    color:orange;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:10px;
}
li:nth-child(2n+2):before {
    content: counter(name, decimal-leading-zero);
    font-size:26px;
    color:green;
    margin-right:10px;
}
li:nth-child(2n+3):before {
    content: counter(name, lower-roman);
    font-size:26px;
    color:red;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the final list content within another element, you can style the index and content separately, as in:

```
<ol><li><span>some text</span></li></ol>
```

With associated CSS:

```
ol li { color: red; }
ol li span { color: blue; }
```